# Recursive function that returns $.Deferred() with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a recursive function that returns a `$.Deferred();`

The function is as follows:

```
var myTest = function (i, deferred) {
    if (!deferred) {
        deferred = $.Deferred();
    }

    if (i < 3) {
        i++;
        console.log("Recursion (" + i + ")!");
        return myTest(i, deferred);
    } else if (i === 3) {
        console.log("Resolving!");
        return deferred.resolve("Woohoo, reached " + i + "!");
    }
}

/* Call it */
myTest(0).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This gives the expected output of:

```
Recursion (1)!
Recursion (2)!
Recursion (3)!
Resolving!
Woohoo, reached 3!
```

But if I change `line 8` to be

```
setTimeout(function() {
    return myTest(i, deferred);
}, 500);
```

It fails. How can I add a timeout into my function but achieve the same result?

[JsFiddle original code](https://jsfiddle.net/xn6t1tzx/)

[JsFiddle with timeout](https://jsfiddle.net/83u2v028/)

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do?  The logic doesn't really appear to be using the deferred in any way.  It is only at the very last iteration returning a forced resolved deferred.

Comment: it fails because the function isn't going to wait to be able to return something. What is the higher level objective?

Comment: @charlietfl the real world objective is to wait for a select list to finish loading so I can access its value before executing my function. I can't change how the select is populated. I can't alter how that populates unfortunately.

Comment: that doesn't explain the recursive part though

Comment: @charlietfl I need to run my function, if the selected value of the select list is still null, wait 500ms (because it's an ajax get and I can't access that function) and then recursively call function again, if it's now loaded then continue on with the rest of the function. I basically just need to wait a small amount of time before I recursively call the function again until it completes.

Comment: use the ajax callbacks to run your code when request has completed. Sounds like you are approaching this backwards

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using a recursive poll instead of allowing a promise to do the "waiting" for you. A promise is an abstraction of a value that is not yet known, with a `.then()` method that allows you to specify an action to be undertaken when the unknown value becomes known.

Comment: A promise is precisely what you want in an AJAX scenario, which is why `jQuery.ajax()` (and similar in other libs) returns a promise. By exploiting the returned promise correctly, you don't need to poll, but you also don't need to create/resolve your own Deferred.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your trying...

```js
var myTest = function (i) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (i < 3) {
      i++;
      console.log("Iteration (" + i + ")!");
    } else {
      console.log("Resolving!");
      deferred.resolve("Woohoo, reached " + i + "!");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
  
  return deferred;
}

/* Call it */
myTest(0).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```